# Passing position of element in std::map as argument to called function

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, stdmap

Say, I have two functions:

```
int methodA(int);
int methodB(int);
```

To avoid repetition of the given below big chunk of code I want create a separate function (say, `funcToAvoidRepeatedCode`), which takes function pointer:

```
{
    //...many lines of code

    std::multimap< size_t, std::pair<char, size_t> >::iterator it;

    //...many lines of code

    methodA(it->first); OR methodB(it->second.second);  // << This is the only difference. 

    //...many lines of code
}
```

I know how to pass the function pointer using `std::function`. I am looking to change the above lines of code into this form:

```
void funcToAvoidRepeatedCode(funcPtr, ?????){

    //...many lines of code

    std::multimap< size_t, std::pair<timelineWeakRef, size_t> >::iterator it;

    //...many lines of code

    funcPtr(???????);
                ^~~~~~What kind of parameter I can pass to 
                      funcToAvoidRepeatedCode() to differentiate the                                          
                      position (first or second.second) in map element?

    //...many lines of code
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: please clarify what is the condition that should trigger `methodA` to be invoked and when `methodB` should be called

Comment: That big code is part of two `switch-case`. So, i am trying to make them concise. Note that there are other `switch-case`s as well which don't use this code. So I can't put it before or after `switch`, as it is not common to all cases.

Comment: yes, but it is not very clear **when** do you wish `methodA` to be invoked and **when** `methodB`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how that can be relevant in getting answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but you clearly have some kind of condition there that indicates whether you should use `methodA` or `methodB`. So why don't you pass that condition into the function instead and avoid using function pointers altogether.

```
void funcToAvoidRepeatedCode(condition) 
{
    if(condition)
    {
        methodA(...);
    }
    else
    {
        methodB(...);
    }
}
```

Passing a function pointer would be required if an arbitrary function of some signature can be passed (e.g. the comparator in `sort()`), but in this case it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information given, there's a simple way to achieve this: Write another set of wrapper functions.

```
int methodAWrapper(std::multimap< size_t, std::pair<char, size_t> >::iterator it) {
    return methodA(it->first);
}

int methodBWrapper(std::multimap< size_t, std::pair<char, size_t> >::iterator it) {
    return methodB(it->second.second);
}
```

Then instead of passing `methodA` or `methodB` as the function pointer, you pass `methodAWrapper` or `methodBWrapper`.

`funcToAvoidRepeatedCode` then simply does

```
void funcToAvoidRepeatedCode(funcPtr) {
    ...
    funcPtr(it);
    ...
}
```

This way `funcToAvoidRepeatedCode` contains only the common code and all differences are extracted into helper methods A and B. (If there are no other uses of `methodA` and `methodB`, you can even inline them into `methodAWrapper` and `methodBWrapper`, so the number of functions stays the same.)

Comment: Hmm..Good workaround. but what if, at some other places, I what to pass integral values **directly** like `funcPtr(10)`. Your solution would kill that possibility unfortunately. :( Upvoted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SauravSahu Yes, but that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: yeah, agree. I wanted to keep my question simple, so removed it.